# Manually compute bcrypt "hashes" (and save in db) for Grails/Spring Security REST users

Tags: grails, spring-security, bcrypt

I need to mass set hundreds of passwords in the database. While I realize I could write some sort of service to go through Grails, the requirement is that I do the update strictly in SQL.

I don't mean to say I need to use some DB-built-in encrypt() or password() function, I just mean the overwrite of the user.password field should be SQL-scriptable. And for security/logging reasons, I'd rather *not* do the hashing within the DB.

How the hash gets generated is wide open so long as it can be easily automated -- the simpler the better. (Yes, crypto purists, I recognize bcrypt output is not a true hash.) I've tried a couple things, one that works but is time prohibitive while the other just "doesn't work" (Grails rejects the password during authentication):

1. There's an online generation tool at http://bcrypthashgenerator.apphb.com/. If I go here and input a string and then save that output as the user's password field in the db, all works. However, they've got built-in protection against automating calls and I'd respect their wishes than try to get around.
2. There's a password_hash function built in to PHP That supports bcrypt. I've tried using the output of this call but Grails doesn't like it (i.e., it tells me my password is invalid): `echo password_hash('test', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`. If I could somehow get this to work it'd be easy enough to just hit this over and over and collect my output.

Preference is to i) find something that works but ii) would like to know why option #2 does not but #1 does.

Comment: Could you show more of option #2? How do you verify the hash? By the way, there are worse hash functions than bcrypt, certainly to hash passwords. May purists would be pretty happy I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's password_hash() after 5.3.7 uses the `$2y$` prefix, while that site (and likely your install) use `$2a$`.

> $2a$ - The current key used to identify this scheme. Since a major
>   security flaw was discovered in 2011 in a third-party implementation
>   of the algorithm,[12] hashes indicated by this string are now
>   ambiguous and might have been generated by the flawed implementation,
>   or a subsequent fixed, implementation. The flaw may be triggered by
>   some password strings containing non-ASCII characters, such as
>   specially crafted password strings.
>
> $2y$ - Post-2011 bug discovery, $2y$ may be used to unambiguously use
>   the new, corrected algorithm. On an implementation suffering from the
>   bug, $2y$ simply won't work. On a newer, fixed implementation, it will
>   produce the same result as using $2a$.

So it looks like your Grails installation is using a vulnerable version of bcrypt. If it were patched, the PHP-encoded `$2y$` version would (should?) work.